# Idiomatic way to optionally add one item to an iterator?

Tags: rust

I'd like to take an iterator from a `Vec` and sometimes include an additional item outside the `Vec` without constructing a new vector.

I figured I could combine `.chain()` and `std::iter::once`, but of course, the return types then differ.

```
fn a(append: &str) {
    let pieces = vec!["a", "b", "c"];
    let myiter = pieces.iter();
    if append != "" {
        myiter = myiter.chain(std::iter::once(&append));
    }
    for s in myiter {
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}
```

No matter what I try, I can't seem to find a type that works for this case.

Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=52b281beade8b882be9adbc5bd2a9e4a